# How can I make the following conversion in VLC from the commandline?

Tags: command-line, conversion, vlc-media-player

I find the command line documentation a little overwhelming, given that I know almost nothing about codecs and the like...

So the following is exactly what I'm doing in VLC (1.1.11) and it would be great to know what the **exact command line equivalent** of this would be:

- in Media -> Convert/Save

  - add a file and click on Convert/Save
  - add the name of the destination file
- in Settings -> Profile

  - select "Audio - MP3"
- click Start

Answer (score 33):

**Short answer**

```
vlc -I dummy input.wav ":sout=#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=192}:std{dst=output.mp3,access=file}" vlc://quit
```

This will transcode `input.wav` and save the result in `output.mp3`.
`ab=192` is the audio bitrate of the output file.

**Long answer**

If you want to find out the corresponding command line of a VLC conversion initiated from the GUI, you can do this:

1. From a terminal/console, start vlc like this `vlc -vv`
2. Start a conversion in the VLC GUI as normal.
3. Scroll back in the console history and find the line starts with `qt4 interface debug: Transcode MRL:`
4. The rest of that line contains the corresponding vlc command line parameter.

Note: My version of VLC is `2.1.0-git Rincewind` and I'm on Linux...

Comment: Great Answer thanks a lot. Is it possible that some parts of the command (mpga,bitrate) from the short answer are dependent on the input-file (other than the name of course)? Since I do get a different result than when doing it within the Gui: your command -> ~60MB, GUI -> ~40MB.  Actually I do it just to reindex an mp3-file so it's an mp3-to-mp3-"conversion", so your solution would work for me, but it could be interesting for people searching for this.

I'm on windows tried to get the long answer to work in the command line and in cygwin but didn't get any output in the console.

Comment: `acodec` and `ab` does not care about the input file. However, the input file must have an audio track for these to be effective.
By default, the GUI transcodes to MP3 with 128 kb/s bitrate. With my command, you had 192 kb/s as bitrate. 60 / 40 = 192 / 128.

Comment: What did you mean with reindexing an mp3-file?

Comment: Awesome thanks for the explanation.
What I mean with reindexing based on a users point of view is trying to solve the following: Arbitrary access of specific time points doesn't work with the original, e.g. I'm playing it in my MP3-Player try to repeat the last few seconds and it might actually go forward. You hear sth. at 45 minutes 30 seconds but when you manually fast-forward so that 45 min. 30sec is displayed it is at a completely different point. I don't have this with other mp3s only from a certain source and doing this conversion solves it.

Comment: Jennifer: Feel free to accept my answer if you are satisfied with it. :)

Answer (score 13):

I tried following the other answer in windows, but I couldn't get the logging to work correctly on the command line, so here is what I did:

**METHOD 1**

I was able to use VLC's internal logging window to see it:

Open VLC, go to Tools -> Messages

Set Verbosity to 2 (Debug)

Then do your conversion, and everything will be logged in the messages window. Do a search for "`sout=#transcode`" or "`qt4 debug`" to find the line with the conversion settings.

[Source](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=101724)

**METHOD 2**

Instead of looking at the log, you can view the profile directly. If you want to use custom settings, just create a new profile of the settings you want.

The profiles (custom and built in) are stored in an ini file, located at

```
%AppData%\vlc\vlc-qt-interface.ini
```

for me this is

```
C:\Users\chiliNUT\AppData\Roaming\vlc\vlc-qt-interface.ini
```

The profiles are located under the section called

```
[codecs-profiles]
```

[Source](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=113653)

A sample from my file is:

```
[codecs-profiles]
1\Profile-Name=Video - VP80 + Vorbis (Webm)
1\Profile-Value="video_enable=yes;video_codec=VP80;vcodec_bitrate=2000;vcodec_framerate=0;vcodec_width=0;vcodec_height=0;audio_enable=yes;audio_codec=vorb;acodec_bitrate=128;acodec_channels=2;acodec_samplerate=44100;muxer_mux=webm"
2\Profile-Name=Video - H.264 + MP3 (TS)
2\Profile-Value="audio_enable=yes;audio_codec=mpga;acodec_bitrate=128;acodec_channels=2;acodec_samplerate=44100;video_enable=yes;video_codec=h264;vcodec_bitrate=800;vcodec_qp=0;vcodec_framerate=0;vcodec_width=0;vcodec_height=0;muxer_mux=ts"
```

...and there are 22 more. My custom profiles are at the bottom.

Using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, VLC 2.1.3 Rincewind

Answer (score 2):

While the above answers where useful in helping me arrive at an answer to the question, they did not work as perhaps because they do not work on Windows (10) or VLC has since been updated to accept different switches. In particular, I will expand upon [joctee's answer](https://superuser.com/a/390240/741731)

```
vlc -I dummy input.wav ":sout=#transcode{acodec=mpga,ab=192}:std{dst=output.mp3,access=file}" vlc://quit
```

Here `-I dummy` runs vlc without showing the GUI and `vlc://quit` closes vlc once the conversion is complete.

On Windows 10, running `3.0.12` I need to run the following command (simplified).

```
vlc input --sout="[TRANSCODECOMMAND"]
```

Where input is the input file name and output is sout capture from the debugger.

Full example, in my case to convert an MP3 to a WAVE file:

```
vlc _AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-G2-0.mp3 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=s16l,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=_AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-G2-0-44100k.wav}" vlc://quit
```

Additionally, to capture the "sout" command, in the VLC GUI go to Tools -> Messages and change Verbosity to 2 as descibed by [chiliNUT](https://superuser.com/a/846237/741731) and run the conversion in the GUI.

This gave the following debug output in the first 3 lines.

```
qt debug: MRL(s) passed to the Sout: 1
qt debug: MRL(s) passed to the Sout: file:///C:/Users/alexh/source/repos/WaveEditor/WaveEditor/bin/Debug/samples/_AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-A2-0.mp3
qt debug: Transcode MRL: sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=s16l,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=wav,dst='C:/Users/alexh/source/repos/WaveEditor/WaveEditor/bin/Debug/samples/_AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-A2-0.wav'}
```

From that output copy everything from `#transcode` to the end of the line and pass it as the parameter to `--sout[TranscodeParameter]`.

From the above example `[TranscoderPameter]`

```
#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=s16l,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=wav,dst='C:/Users/alexh/source/repos/WaveEditor/WaveEditor/bin/Debug/samples/_AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-A2-0.wav'
```

So the full argument is:

```
--sout="#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=s16l,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=_AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-G2-0-44100k.wav}"
```

Note you can use relative path names if working in a different directory and run vlc using the full path to the executable.

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" _AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-G2-0.mp3 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=s16l,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=_AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-G2-0-44100k.wav}" vlc://quit
```