# This video has not been mixed with the audio because the audio stream has a different format

Tags: windows, audio, video, vlc-media-player, download-manager

I face the following problem from time to time when I want to download some video:

> This video has not been mixed with the audio because the audio stream
> has a different format

[image]

I want to know How to fix this problem if possible and If not How to merge the output which is two separate files:

```
TS file ---> video 
AAC file --> Audio
```

I Use VLC program but it takes a lot of time because I have to pass many steps to merge just a one item and I have so many files separated!

---

If I have directory hierarchy like that:

```
Parent
    |
   Folder1 -->Sub1 --->1.ts
                   --->1_audio.aac

           -->Sub2 --->2.ts
                   --->2_audio.aac
 
   Folder2 -->Sub1 --->1.ts
                   --->1_audio.aac
```

How to convet it to

```
  Parent
    |
   Folder1 -->Sub1 --->1.mp4

           -->Sub2 --->2.mp4
                   
 
   Folder2 -->Sub1 --->1.mp4
```

Comment: May I suggest youtube-dl? Don’t know where you’re downloading from, but youtube-dl basically does it all.

Comment: There are many video/audio mixing programs, some dead simple - see [here](https://windowsreport.com/mix-audio-and-video-app/). However, I'm wondering if the problem arises because the video already contains an audio stream - are you trying to replace or add a sound-track and the two are not of the same format?

Comment: @harrymc I try to download a video through IDM from pluralsight to watch it later but I face this problem!! And I don’t know why this happens and how to merge them easily

Comment: Something is wrong here. Could you post online (OneDrive, Dropbox etc) an example?

Comment: Another question: Have you tried to play the TS file by itself to see if it already has audio?

Comment: @harrymc the ts has no audio, i get two files one ts and the other .aac for audio I don’t why but i want to merge them without a lot of steps in vlc app

Comment: It's rare for VLC to fail. A small sample will help.

Comment: @harrymc vlc succeed but if i want to merge like 40 files it will take a lot of steps = a lot of time because i have to select pair by pair

Comment: VLC can be automated and run via the command-line. The command is a bit complicated, but you can create it automatically by doing manually the merge for one set of files, then duplicating it for all the other files. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1654871/8672) for an example. If this works for you, I can put up an answer.

Comment: @harrymc : I edit my question, Could U take a look please, Could U make the answer for the example above so that I can follow the steps easily

Comment: I added the command-line `mp4box` utility to my answer, which is truly simple to use. If you need help with writing a script for automating it, let me know, but please try `mp4box` once on one of your videos to be sure that it's working for you.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks a lot I will try it at night because I'm outside right now, and I will be so grateful if U can help me to create the script.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare: Let me know if `mp4box` works, and I'll help with the script.

Comment: @harrymc I edit my question , It works perfectly, I don't know why I get this message `Invalid Next ...` but I play `1.mp4` and it works perfectly. Now Could U help me please to run a script to override every couple files`(ts & aac)` by `mp4` in the same folder please.

Comment: Good, I'll look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @harrymc Thank U so much, I'm waiting

Comment: I added the `.bat` script to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLC can be automated to run via the command-line. Once the
command-line is formulated, it's possible to embed it into a script.

The command-parameters are a bit complicated, but there is an
easy way to have VLC create it for you.

The idea is to do manually the merge for one set of files, then
create the command-line from the verbose output.

This is described in the post
[How can I make the following conversion in VLC from the commandline?](https://superuser.com/questions/388511/how-can-i-make-the-following-conversion-in-vlc-from-the-commandline),
and especially in the
[answer by Alexander Higgins](https://superuser.com/questions/388511/how-can-i-make-the-following-conversion-in-vlc-from-the-commandline/1654871#1654871).

The simplified format of the command is:

```
vlc input --sout="[TRANSCODECOMMAND"]
```

Doing the merge after setting in VLC menu *Tools > Messages* the
`Verbosity` to `2`, will give a line such as:

```
qt debug: Transcode MRL: sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=s16l,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file{no-overwrite},mux=wav,dst='C:/Users/alexh/source/repos/WaveEditor/WaveEditor/bin/Debug/samples/_AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-A2-0.wav'}
```

Copying everything starting with `#transcode` gives the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" _AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-G2-0.mp3 --sout="#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=s16l,ab=160,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:std{access=file,mux=wav,dst=_AI_NylStr_MonRibb_Sft-G2-0-44100k.wav}" vlc://quit
```

---

Another useful program that is very easy to use is
[MP4Box](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/MP4Box),
which can
[downloaded here](https://www.videohelp.com/software/MP4Box).

To add the audio to the video, you could do:

```
"C:\Program Files\GPAC\mp4box.exe" -add 1.aac 1.ts
```

This will do an in-place replace of `1.ts`, so will destroy the
original file.

To create an `.mp4` video will require two lines:

```
"C:\Program Files\GPAC\mp4box.exe" -add 1.ts -new 1.mp4
"C:\Program Files\GPAC\mp4box.exe" -add 1.aac 1.mp4
```

---

Here is a batch script that enters all the sub-folders and
creates `.mp4` files from the `.ts` and `.aac` files.
The target `.mp4` file will have the same name as that of the
video file.

The `.ts` and `.aac` files are not deleted, for safety.
They can be deleted later if everything works as expected.
I suggested taking a backup of the parent folder,
just in case.

Here is the `.bat` file. It should be put inside the Parent folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%D in ("*") DO (
  echo ** Entering folder : %%D
  cd "%%D"
  for %%F in (*.ts) do set "VIDEO=%%F"
  for %%G in (*.aac) do set "AUDIO=%%G"
  set "TARGET=!VIDEO:.ts=!"
  echo ** Found: Video=!VIDEO!  Audio=!AUDIO!  Target=!TARGET!
  "C:\Program Files\GPAC\mp4box.exe" -add "!VIDEO!" -new "!TARGET!.mp4"
  "C:\Program Files\GPAC\mp4box.exe" -add "!AUDIO!" "!TARGET!.mp4"
  cd ..
)
```

---

For two levels down, use two
[FOR /D](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
commands:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%D in ("*") DO (
echo ** Entering folder : %%D
cd "%%D"
for /d %%E in ("*") DO (
  echo ** Entering sub-folder : %%E
  cd "%%E"
  for %%F in (*.ts) do set "VIDEO=%%F"
  for %%G in (*.aac) do set "AUDIO=%%G"
  set "TARGET=!VIDEO:.ts=!"
  echo ** Found: Video=!VIDEO!  Audio=!AUDIO!  Target=!TARGET!
  "C:\Program Files\GPAC\mp4box.exe" -add "!VIDEO!" -new "!TARGET!.mp4"
  "C:\Program Files\GPAC\mp4box.exe" -add "!AUDIO!" "!TARGET!.mp4"
  del "!VIDEO!"
  del "!AUDIO!"
  cd ..
)
cd ..
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I put the script in the parent folder but it doesn't work, I have to put it in each individual folder to work. I'm so sorry if I didn't explain the case as I should, I have nested folders = `three levels( the parent, level1 level2, then the two files)` ts file and the audio file with `_audio` at the end of the audio file name. and I want the script to delete the two files. just the mp4 file in each folder. I edited my question to illustrate the hierarchy of folders.

Comment: Could U read my comment plz 

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare: No problem. Done.

Comment: U are just amazing, the last thing, I want to delete both `ts,aac` files, I want just mp4 file please.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare: Added to the second script. Good night.

Answer (score 3):

It probably is easier to use ffmpeg to do a quick merge of your files than to do it by loading both files in VLC simultaneously.

You can just use a command line like powershell or cmd if you prefer and write

```
ffmpeg -i video.ts -i audio.aac -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

If you don't have ffmpeg installed, there are precompiled binaries on the official [ffmpeg website](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

---

Deeper going explanations:
ffmpeg itself is a command line tool. There are so many features that a gui would inevitably be very complex and frustrating to use as it would be convoluted. There are compiled versions of [ffmpeg with gui](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpegyag/) but I would not recommend to use them as they are always made for a specific purpose which never completely matches with yours. Instead I would use the command line version by [gyan](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) which indeed is linked to on the official website above. Just put it in a folder contained in your PATH variable or directly execute it from the folder. Use the command above, replace `video.ts` with the path to your video file, `audio.aac` with the path to your audio file and `output.mp4` with a path to a new file that will be generated. Think of it as the usual "Save As..." option. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Could I ask If `ffmpeg` has exe to download cuz the site just has source code

Comment: Plz Could U give me more details I imagined that it was an application with easy to use interface